# Rewrite Url in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite this url

```
http://mywebsite.local/watch/serie/le-transporteur-la-s%C3%A9rie
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.local/watch-serie-le-transporteur-la-s%C3%A9rie.html
```

how i can proceed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Comment: Check [this section in docs](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L59) and figure out something in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a rewrite condition in the htaccess file and config file
Then, in your route file you need to use :

```
$route['watch-serie-le-transporteur-la-s%C3%A9rie\.html']='folder/controller/method';
```

or

```
$route['(:any)\.html'] = 'folder/controller/method';
```